# calculate ta.highest() for the length of an opened trade

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to calculate the highest high while a trade is opened. I already implemented the function Get_Number_Of_Bars_In_Trade() which returns how many bars are closed in the opened position. On the entry bar it returns 1 and for every new bar it returns +1. So as long, as there's a trade opened the value of Get_Number_Of_Bars_In_Trade() return something bigger then 0.

I want to put the return of Get_Number_Of_Bars_In_Trade() into the ta.highest() function, to get the highest high within the time of the opened trade. But Pinescript somehow doesn't allow that and tells me I should extract the call for consistency. The Script compiles but the Get_In_Trade_High() Function seems to be aborted and the log doesn't show.

My Idea is, on the close of every bar while the trade is opened I want to get the highest high for the time of the trade. I need that value for adding a trailing stop.

```
Get_In_Trade_High() =>
    if( strategy.position_size != 0 and barstate.isconfirmed ) 
        bar_count = Get_Number_Of_Bars_In_Trade() 
        trade_high = ta.highest(bar_count)
        log.info("Bar Count: {0} \nhigh: {1}", bar_count, trade_high )
```

I don't understand why this isn't working, because if I just put hardcoded numbers into ta.highest() the script is working and the log is showing.

when I leave the trade_high Variable from log.info line the log gets printed:

```
Get_In_Trade_High() =>
    if( strategy.position_size != 0 and barstate.isconfirmed ) 
        bar_count = Get_Number_Of_Bars_In_Trade() 
        trade_high = ta.highest(bar_count)
        log.info("Bar Count: {0} \nhigh: {1}", bar_count  )
```

I don't want to create a loop function which checks the highs "manually", since it would be so much easier and cleaner to just use the ta.highest() function.

and here's the Get_Number_Of_Bars_In_Trade() Function:

```
Get_Number_Of_Bars_In_Trade() =>
    if( strategy.position_size != 0 and barstate.isconfirmed )
        bars = bar_index - ( strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index(strategy.opentrades - 1) -2 )
        log.info(" Number of Bars: {0} \nentry bar: {1} \ncurrent bar: {2}", bars, strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index(strategy.opentrades - 1), bar_index)
        bars
    else
        bars = 0
```

Am I not getting something or is it simply not possible to do it this way in pinescript?

Do you have any suggestions how I can solve this issue?

Comment: after trying a few things this way it's working without the ta.highest() function.

Get_In_Trade_High() =>
    in_trade_high = 0.0
    for int i = 1 to Get_Number_Of_Bars_In_Trade()
        in_trade_high := math.max(high[i], high)
    in_trade_high

still I'd like to know if there is a way to do this with ta.highest() function?